# Mutable global variables don't get hide in python functions, right?

Tags: python, scope

Please see the following code:

```
def good():
  foo[0] = 9         # why this foo isn't local variable who hides the global one

def bad():
  foo    = [9, 2, 3] # foo is local, who hides the global one

for func in [good, bad]:
  foo = [1,2,3]

  print('Before "{}": {}'.format(func.__name__, foo))
  func()
  print('After  "{}": {}'.format(func.__name__, foo))
```

The result is as below:

```
# python3 foo.py
Before "good": [1, 2, 3]
After  "good": [9, 2, 3]
Before "bad" : [1, 2, 3]
After  "bad" : [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're not setting foo, you're getting something *in* foo (foo[0] to be exact).

In `bad` you create a new variable `foo`. In `good` you do something like `foo.set(0, 9)` (set item 0 to value 9). Which is *using* a variable, and not defining a new name.

Comment: I guess so, but why differ the logic between setting and using? If in good, you also have to declare global foo, isn't it more consistent and preventing user shooting their own foot?

Answer (score 0):

Variables will look to their inner scope first then to outer scopes in python.  For instance:

```
FOO = 'global'

def printfoo():
    print FOO
# prints 'global'

def printfoolocal():
    FOO = 'local'
    print FOO
# prints 'local'
```

If you'd like to modify a globally scoped variable, you need to use the `global` keyword

```
def modifyfoo():
    global FOO
    FOO = 'modified'
print FOO
# prints 'modified'
```

Comment: I know this behavior, just curious about the differences in both cases. I think @extraneon answered my question. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To make simple, python first look in the local variables and after in the global ones. (For reading or for creating a variable)

So, in good, you take the foo variable : No local foo variable and a global foo variable => you take the global one and you modify it.

In bad, you create a new (local) variable, so the global one is not modified.

You can specify that a variable is global with the global keyword :

```
def good2():
    global foo
    foo    = [9, 2, 3]
```

Comment: > "So, in good, you take the foo variable : No local foo variable and a global foo variable => you take the global one and you modify it."

My question is exactly why wouldn't this behavior happen in 'bad'. What are the rules here?

Answer (score 0):

If, like good, you want to replace the contents of the list foo, then you could assign to a slice of the whole list like:

```
def good2():
    foo[:] = [9, 2, 3]
```

Just like where `good` assigned to one element of the list, this replaces the whole contents.

In `bad` you were binding a **new** list to the name foo.